# Encoding a file with ord function

Tags: python, python-3.x, encoding, ord

I'm trying to encode a file and output the encode into a new file, but I got this error:

```
TypeError: ord() expected string of length 1, but int found
```

My code:

```
from sys import argv, exit


def encode(data):
    encoded = ''
    while data:
        current = data[0]
        count = 1
        for i in data[1:]:
            if i == current:
                count += 1
            else:
                break
            if count == 255:
                break

        encoded += '{}{}'.format(chr(ord(current) & 255), chr(count & 255)) #error occurs here.
        data = data[count:]

    return encoded


if __name__ == '__main__':
    if len(argv) < 2:
        print('Please specify input file!')
        exit(0)
    with open(argv[1], 'rb') as (f):
        data = f.read()
    with open(argv[1] + '.out', 'wb') as (f):
        f.write(encode(data))
```

Additional question: How do I decode the encoded file?

Comment: try `chr(ord(str(current)) & 255` instead of `chr(ord(current) & 255`

Comment: yeah, because `current` can be more than one digit... May I ask what do you want `chr(ord(current) & 255)` to be? I mean do you expect a number of a character?

Comment: Tried that; didn't work. Got this error instead: `TypeError: ord() expected a character, but string of length 2 found`

Answer (score 0):

You are reading bytes (`open(..., 'rb')`), so when you take one element of the byte string, you get a byte, ie. a number. This number already is the character code, so just leave out the `ord`. Alternatively, you could open the file without the `b` modifier (`open(..., 'r')`), which will return a string; I would advise to keep it as a byte string though (or you could run into encoding issues if you are parsing something non-ascii).

You will run into a similar problem saving your file: you cannot write a string into a file opened with the `b` modifier. Since you have characters outside the ascii range (>128), writing as a string is not a good idea, since python will try to encode your characters (eg. in UTF-8), and you will end up with completely different bytes. Therefore, the best solution probably is not to concat your data to a string in your loop (the part where you do `'{}{}'.format(...)`, but to have a list (`encoded = []`, concat with `encoded.append(current)`) and convert that to a byte string using `bytes(encoded)` after your loop. You can then pass that to `write` without a problem.

As for how to decode your file, you can just open the file like you do for encoding, read two bytes `b1` and `b2`, and append `[b1]*b2` to your output (again, as a list), and convert that to a byte string with `bytes()`.